# How to rollback new records if a later record fails to add in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In my controller I have code similar to the following:

```
$a = new A();
$a->content = "blah";
$a->save();

$b = new B();
$b->content = "blah2";
$b->a_id = $a->id;
$b->save();

$c = new C();
$c->content = "blah3";
$c->b_id = $b->id;
```

where `A`, `B` and `C` are all models.

As you can see, each model assignment relies on the previous record being assigned correctly (i.e. `C` relies on `B`, and `B` relies on `C`)

I want to make the code so that if one of the new records fails, it deletes all previous records (i.e. all or nothing).

For example,

- If `A` fails to save, the code ends gracefully
- If `B` fails to save, it removes its corresponding `A` record
- If `C` fails to save, it removes its corresponding `B` and `A` record

How do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's really simple, use database transactions:

```
DB::transaction(function () {

    $a = new A();
    $a->content = "blah";
    $a->save();

    $b = new B();
    $b->content = "blah2";
    $b->a_id = $a->id;
    $b->save();

    $c = new C();
    $c->content = "blah3";
    $c->b_id = $b->id;

});
```

Everything here will be done automatically - if any of above fail, result will be same as the code inside transactions has never been run.

Reference: [Laravel database transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#database-transactions)

**EDIT**

If you need to pass any variables, you need use `use` construction like so:

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($variable1, $variable2) {
  // ...
});
```

Reference: [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Awesome, but how do I pass variables into the anonymous function that is declared outside of the function

Comment: `function() use ($passedVariable1, $passedVariable2[, ...]) { ... }`

Comment: Never even heard of the `use` construction. Thanks a lot!

Comment: can i do this using model instead of DB ?

Comment: @AbdanSyakuro No, you use DB to start transaction, but as you see in example you can have model inside this. Of course, you can also us DB::transaction inside method of model if you do multiple DB operations.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek What happens if I need to access the $a register inside de transaction? It exists inside the transaction or not?